# nginx does not forward traffic with TLS v1.1

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

Im using nginx 1.18.0 on an Ubuntu 22.04 server machine as a reverse proxy. Everything works fine except for one thing.

A client uses a desktop application, which sends https requests to a specific website, using TLS v1.1 but it gets no response.

Traffic arrives to proxy, as I can see using tcpdump, but nginx does not log those requests. I find nothing related inside access.log or error.log. And of course my backend web servers don't get those requests.

If I hit the same website through my web browser (using TLS v1.2) it works. Request is logged in access.log and proxied to my backend webserver.

So my first thought was to enable TLS v1.1 on this website.conf file using the below directive:

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

But that did not work for me. Is there anything else I can try? Maybe another http version or specific ssl ciphers?

Isn't it weird that this traffic is not logged in nginx log files?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `using tcpdump` And the TLS handshake? That should have everything you need. On both packet captures.

Comment: `Isn't it weird that this traffic is not logged in nginx log files?` It is expected behavior when the connection fails the handshake. The connection fails at the network layer and never makes it to the application layer.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: @Greg Askew, yeah that makes sense

Comment: @djdomi, well I got a proper answer from Ace.

Comment: but keep it in mind for the next time ;)

Comment: @GregAskew+ access.log won't contain anything if the handshake failed but error.log should. (Only if IP or TCP level failed would you see no log, and then it wouldn't be in tcpdump either.)  cladmin: please be more specific about what you see in tcpdump for the failed attempt. Does the SYN-exchange work? Do you receive ClientHello, and what is in it? Do you send ServerHello, or Alert, or something else, and with what contents?

Answer (score 1):

See also here Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't support TLSv1 at all, even not at openssl (library) level
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75638170/19423269

Comment: Thank you @Ace for your response. Well that being the case, I think it is not an option for me to try enabling TLSv.1. After talking to the app's dev team the decision is to update the application so it can use newer versions of TLS. I think this is the best option in order not to compromise security. I could move the website back to the old webserver in order to work until updates are made.
Thank you for your time, and your helpful response.